# Post file using jquery in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I want to post a csv file to django view using jquery

```
<form  id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="ListFile" id="ListFile" />
<button type="button" onclick="csv_send">upload</button>
</form><br>
```

js is:

```
function csv_send(){
var data = {
'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
'data': $("#ListFile").val()
}
/*$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:'/list/create/',
  cache:false,
  dataType:'json',
  data:data,
  success: function(result) {
     console.log("ok")
    }
 });*/
}
```

django views.py:

```
def createlist(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file =  request.FILES
```

here not getting file.
I know getting file using form action.But here i want to post file through javascript because i want response back to javascript after success.
Clearly i want that file in views.py by request.FILES

Comment: you're missing form's param `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko now also print request.FILES['ListName'] gives <MultiValueDict: {}>

Comment: well... the thing is you can't upload file via AJAX. You have to use iframe (I've some library for this purpose here: https://github.com/yedpodtrzitko/ajax-uploader )

Comment: Actualy this question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko there using form action as url

Answer (score 1):

When uploading files, your form must have this attribute:

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

like this:

```
<form  id="form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

[This might help you understand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: Then also print request.FILES gives <MultiValueDict: {}>

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a FormData object and a slightly modified version of basic ajax post:

```
    var data = new FormData();
    var file = null;

    //when uploading a file take the file
    $("#your-file-input-id").on("change", function(){
        file = this.files[0]
    });

    //append the file in the data
    data.append("file", file);

    //append other data
    data.append("message", "some content");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/path',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            //handle success            },
        error: function (data, status, xhr) {
            //handle error
        }

    });
```

In Django you will find the file in **request.FILES['file']**.
I hope this is helpful.